# Grails 2.5 & SpringAcl: aclCacheManager bean not accessible

Tags: hibernate, grails, ehcache

After migrating from 2.4.x to last 2.5.0 release, i've changed some params for hibernate in datasource:

```
cache.region.factory_class =
'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory'
```

and Config.groovy:

```
grails.cache.enabled = true
grails.cache.clearAtStartup = true
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false
beans.cacheManager.cacheManagerName = 'springcacheCacheManager'
beans.cacheManager.shared = true
```

in resources.groovy, the ehcache bean is set up like this:

```
ehcache(EhCacheFactoryBean) { bean ->
        cacheManager = ref("springcacheCacheManager")
        cacheName = "cache"
        eternal = false
        shared = true
        diskPersistent = false
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = "LRU"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap = "10000"
        timeToIdleSeconds = "120"
        timeToLiveSeconds = "120"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk = "10000000"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds = "120"

    }
```

Then, the issue with springAclService with aclCacheManager appears at bootstrap:

```
objc[41029]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. |Loading Grails
2.5.0 |Configuring classpath . |Environment set to development ................................. |Packaging Grails application ........... |Compiling 1 source files .................................................................Log4j consoleLevel: WARN appFile Level: DEBUG .. |Running Grails application objc[41057]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. Log4j consoleLevel: WARN appFile Level: DEBUG Configuring Spring Security Core ... ... finished configuring Spring Security Core Configuring Spring Security ACL ... ... finished configuring Spring Security ACL 2015-03-28 18:53:44,111 ERROR [DefaultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder] - URL mapping argument [exception] with value [(*)] must be a valid class 2015-03-28 18:53:44,113 ERROR [DefaultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder] - URL mapping argument [exception] with value [(*)] must be a valid class 2015-03-28 18:53:45,342 ERROR [GrailsContextLoaderListener] - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'afterAclCollectionRead': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityAclAclService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCacheManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'afterAclCollectionRead': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityAclAclService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCacheManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityAclAclService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCacheManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]     ... 4 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcacheAclCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCacheManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]     ... 4 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcacheAclCache': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aclCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCacheManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]     ... 4 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclCacheManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]     ... 4 more Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]     at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:529)    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:374)  at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:259)    ... 4 more Error |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue trying to upgrade from grails 2.4.3 -> 2.5.0.

I think the problem stems from changes in the way that the new Hibernate/Cache plugins create a CacheManager. From discussions [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-hibernate4-plugin/commit/6a069ed0), [here](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-12120) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/grails-dev-discuss/57bpHvzHH3I/2-6V2JFndqwJ), it looks like newer versions (i.e. those used in grails 2.5.0) do not permit multiple unnamed cache managers, so the spring-security-acl plugin will not be able to create its own manager once the Hibernate CacheManager is created.

I would have thought that naming the hibernate CacheManager would fix this problem (like you've already done),  but no dice.

My temporary (untested) workaround is to add the following to my application's resources.groovy:

```
 aclCacheManager(org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean) {
  shared = true
```

}

I don't actually know if this means that the ACL plugin will now share the same cache manager as Hibernate, but I'm not too fussed about caching right now so I'm happy as long as my application is running.

Try that and see how you get on.